# Programming ATtiny84 using Arduino (Leonardo)

Tags: arduino, attiny, isp

I am trying to program the ATtiny84 using an Arduino (Leonardo). I have seen this [Shrinkify video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30rPt802n1k). -and I have been following this [Programming tutorial](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695).

I have connected everything and am using Arduino 1.0.1 software. I uploaded `ArduinoISP` to the Arduino, selected "board" *ATtiny84 (Internal 1 MHz clock)*, and selected "programmer" *Arduino as ISP*.

When I try to upload the blink example, I get this error:

> Binary sketch size: 880 bytes (of a 8,192 byte maximum)
>
> avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny84
>
> avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature. 
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override 
>            this check.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Should I upload by pressing "Upload" or "Upload using programmer"? (I have tried both - with same result)
- What does "use -F to override" mean?

**Update:**

I have now found that my problem is that Leonardo can not be used like this. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PeterVH provides all the info needed to use the Arduino Leonardo as an ISP with the arduino ide (version 1.0.1):

[ArduinoISP on the Leonardo](http://petervanhoyweghen.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/arduinoisp-on-the-leonardo/)